# PostgreSQL create function to export symbolised data in batches by interval

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, intervals, export-to-csv, dynamic-sql

I would like to export records from a database table, to a CSV file, in batches based upon time intervals. I would usually use python and create different queries for this kind of thing in a for loop and then execute them. For example I would typically create a query such as:

```
COPY (SELECT 'log_time:' || logtime, 'firstname:' || firstname FROM tablename WHERE log_time >= 2016-01-01 00:00:00 AND log_time < 2016-01-01 23:59:59) TO '/tmp/data_2016-01-01.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV
```

And I would loop through several days performing the query above and editing the interval accordingly, in order to export the records day by day. For example the next query in the for loop would be:

```
COPY (SELECT 'log_time:' || logtime, 'firstname:' || firstname FROM tablename WHERE log_time >= 2016-01-02 00:00:00 AND log_time < 2016-01-02 23:59:59) TO '/tmp/data_2016-01-02.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV
```

Just to clarify the part of the query that states `'log_time:' || logtime, 'first name:'` is required for the data mining which occurs on the exported data.

Also note the filename varies to contain the date in question (/tmp/data_2016-01-01.csv, /tmp/data_2016-01-02.csv etc).

The function query I have come up with so far is something like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION temporal_interval_export_for_mining(timestamp without time zone, timestamp without time zone, interval, text) 
 RETURNS void AS 
$func$
DECLARE
    starttime timestamp without time zone := $1;
    endtime timestamp without time zone := $2;
    interval_length interval := $3;
    tablename := $4;
    file_id = starttime
BEGIN

LOOP
    PERFORM COPY (SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE log_time >= starttime AND log_time < starttime + interval) TO ‘/tmp/data_’ + file_id + ‘.csv’ DELIMITER ',' CSV;
    starttime := starttime + interval;
    file_id   := starttime;
    EXIT WHEN starttime > endtime;
END LOOP;

END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

But this is missing the symbolisation of the fields, and instead has a `select *`. I need some way off automatically retrieving a select on all fields in a table (not just the two listed above) symbolised like `fieldname:fieldvalue`.

Now I don't know anything about creating these functions but I think I understand the above, although there may be an error.

I am willing to accept any method (not just a function) that would simplify the process so that I don't need to loop through a list of dates in my python code and can instead perform the interval processing through the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your purpose you need to use [dynamic SQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN) and [`SECURITY DEFINER`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-createfunction.html) flag. Statement `COPY` has not execution plan, and then disallow using any variables inside - *dynamic SQL* is necessary. `COPY` with access to IO needs superuser rights, that should be used pretty carefully - so you need `SECURITY DEFINER` flag (a owner of this function (creator) have to be user with superuser rights):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION temporal_interval_export_for_mining(starttime timestamp without time zone,
                                                               endtime timestamp without time zone,
                                                               interval_length interval,
                                                               tablename text) 
RETURNS void AS 
$func$
DECLARE
  ctime timestamp without time zone = starttime;
  dsql text;
  expr text = '*';
BEGIN
  -- expr := expr_list(columns_to_array(tablename));
  WHILE ctime < endtime
  LOOP
    dsql := format(
$_$COPY (SELECT %s FROM %I WHERE log_time >= %L AND log_time < %L) TO %L DELIMITER ',' CSV$_$,
                   expr, tablename, ctime, ctime + interval_length,
                   '/tmp/data_' || to_char(ctime, 'YYYY-MM-DD') || '.csv');
    RAISE NOTICE 'Executing query: %', dsql;
    EXECUTE dsql;
    ctime := ctime + interval_length;
  END LOOP; 
  RETURN;
END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql SECURITY DEFINER STRICT;
```

you can call this function with `SELECT`:

```
postgres=# select temporal_interval_export_for_mining(current_timestamp::timestamp without time zone, (current_timestamp + interval '10days')::timestamp without time zone, '1day'::interval, 'foo'::text);
NOTICE:  Executing query: COPY (SELECT * FROM foo WHERE log_time >= '2016-01-17 07:51:48.189734' AND log_time < '2016-01-18 07:51:48.189734') TO '/tmp/data_2016-01-17.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV
NOTICE:  Executing query: COPY (SELECT * FROM foo WHERE log_time >= '2016-01-18 07:51:48.189734' AND log_time < '2016-01-19 07:51:48.189734') TO '/tmp/data_2016-01-18.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV
NOTICE:  Executing query: COPY (SELECT * FROM foo WHERE log_time >= '2016-01-19 07:51:48.189734' AND log_time < '2016-01-20 07:51:48.189734') TO '/tmp/data_2016-01-19.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV
NOTICE:  Executing query: COPY (SELECT * FROM foo WHERE log_time >= '2016-01-20 07:51:48.189734' AND log_time < '2016-01-21 07:51:48.189734') TO '/tmp/data_2016-01-20.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV
NOTICE:  Executing query: COPY (SELECT * FROM foo WHERE log_time >= '2016-01-21 07:51:48.189734' AND log_time < '2016-01-22 07:51:48.189734') TO '/tmp/data_2016-01-21.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV
NOTICE:  Executing query: COPY (SELECT * FROM foo WHERE log_time >= '2016-01-22 07:51:48.189734' AND log_time < '2016-01-23 07:51:48.189734') TO '/tmp/data_2016-01-22.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV
NOTICE:  Executing query: COPY (SELECT * FROM foo WHERE log_time >= '2016-01-23 07:51:48.189734' AND log_time < '2016-01-24 07:51:48.189734') TO '/tmp/data_2016-01-23.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV
NOTICE:  Executing query: COPY (SELECT * FROM foo WHERE log_time >= '2016-01-24 07:51:48.189734' AND log_time < '2016-01-25 07:51:48.189734') TO '/tmp/data_2016-01-24.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV
NOTICE:  Executing query: COPY (SELECT * FROM foo WHERE log_time >= '2016-01-25 07:51:48.189734' AND log_time < '2016-01-26 07:51:48.189734') TO '/tmp/data_2016-01-25.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV
NOTICE:  Executing query: COPY (SELECT * FROM foo WHERE log_time >= '2016-01-26 07:51:48.189734' AND log_time < '2016-01-27 07:51:48.189734') TO '/tmp/data_2016-01-26.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV
 temporal_interval_export_for_mining 
-------------------------------------

(1 row)
```

How to generate name list? It depends on how your Postgres is old. I'll expect 9.1 and higher.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.expr_list(colnames text[])
RETURNS text
LANGUAGE plpgsql AS $function$
DECLARE
  colname text;
  result text;
  expressions text[];
BEGIN
   IF colnames IS NOT NULL THEN
      expressions := '{}';
      FOREACH colname IN ARRAY colnames
      LOOP
        expressions := expressions || format('%L || %I', colname || ':', colname); 
      END LOOP;
      result := array_to_string(expressions, ', ');
    ELSE
      result := '*';
    END IF;
    RETURN result;
  END;
  $function$;

 postgres=# select expr_list(ARRAY['name','surname']);
               expr_list                
----------------------------------------
 'name:' || name, 'surname:' || surname
(1 row)


postgres=# select expr_list(ARRAY(SELECT column_name::text FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name = 'pg_class'));

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 'relname:' || relname, 'relnamespace:' || relnamespace, 'reltype:' || reltype, 'reloftype:' || reloftype, 'relowner:' || relowner, 'relam:' || relam, 'relfilenode:' || relfilenode, 'reltablespace:' || reltablespace, 'relpages:
(1 row)
```

The call can be simplified by custom SQL function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION colums_to_array(text)
RETURNS text[] AS $$
    SELECT ARRAY(SELECT column_name::text
                    FROM information_schema.columns
                   WHERE table_name = $1::name)
$$ LANGUAGE sql;

postgres=# SELECT colums_to_array('foo');
 colums_to_array  
------------------
 {log_time,xx,yy}
```

(1 row)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I understand. I just have one problem, which is that I don't understand how to incorporate my symbolisation into this. I need the function to automatically retrieve a list of all column names and use this to create the query. I.e. Instead of `select *` , I require `select "fieldname1:" || fieldvalue1, "fieldname2:" || fieldvalue2, "fieldname3:" || fieldvalue3`  for a table with 3 fields (columns). Similarly the function should work for a table with 6 fields and automatically create the select accordingly.

Comment: you can add other parameter "columns", and use it in `format` function.

Comment: But how can I get the columns automatically rather than predefining the names? Typically the query will be `SELECT column_name FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name = tablename`. How can I run two queries in the above function, using the output from the first in the second? Currently in my code I perform the query for the column names and then loop through these names creating the query string field by field and then execute it.

Comment: Thanks for all the help. i'm almost there now, and I can follow most of what you have said. I now have these two functions which when run together give me a symbolised list of column names for any "tablename". i.e. `select symbolised_list(colums_to_array(tablename));`

Comment: Now I create a parameter as `symbolised_columns text;`  in the declare for my temporal_interval_export_for_mining function, but how can I set the value of this parameter as the result of the query in my previous comment prior to creating the dsql query `dsql := format(
$_$COPY (SELECT %s FROM %I WHERE log_time >= %L AND log_time < %L) TO %L DELIMITER ',' CSV$_$,
                   symbolised_columns, tablename, ctime, ctime + interval_length,
                   '/tmp/data_' || to_char(ctime, 'YYYY-MM-DD') || '.csv');`

Comment: Im currently working along the following lines to use the result of the query and set the variable. After begin I first run the query  `SELECT symbolised_list(colums_to_array(tablename)) INTO symbolised_columns;` and then the rest of the temporal_interval_export_for_mining function definition is the same with my previous comment applied.

Comment: Thanks for the help this all works fine now. I have just one minor issue. I create this function in my database server. But when run this on the database server from a remote location the output file is always saved to the specified location on the remote machine, how can I make sure the file is always saved locally with respect to where the command is run as opposed to where the database server is?

Comment: Stored procedures are executed on server side (remote side), and remote IO accessible only. There are no possibility to write to file on client side from stored procedure. If you need it, then you need the client side code - it cannot be implemented as stored procedure.